# Constexpr member variables with setters?

Tags: c++, c++11, setter, constexpr

So on my C++ homework assignment the instructions say..

> Create a constexpr member for kUnboundLower and kUnboundUpper.
>
> ...
>
> Create lower bound and upper bound setters and getters.

How is this possible? If something is `constexpr` you can't set it again. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your assignment. constexpr in classes only apply to constructors, and member functions, not members

Answer (score 0):

> If something is constexpr you can't set it again. What am I missing
>   here?

You can modify an object in an constexpr context, but only if the modifications are constexpr.

For instance:

```
constexpr auto foo() -> int { return 24; }

struct X
{
    int x_;
    constexpr auto x() -> int& { return x_; }
};


constexpr auto make_x(int a)
{
    X x{};
    x.x() = a; // invalid if `x()` is not `constexpr`

    return x;
}

auto test()
{
    constexpr auto x = make_x(24);
}
```

Please imagine a more practical example where this is useful, my brain is too tired right now to come up with a practical example, but there is, for instance when you can't create the object from the constructor, but need to set members individually after creation.

Comment: A more practical example: `++it` of a (custom) iterator of a (const) range.

Answer (score 0):

> How is this possible? If something is constexpr you can't set it again. What am I missing here?

Not sure, but is seems to me you've misunderstood your assignment.

> Create a ctor that accepts: [lower bound, upper bound).

Your class define a range, with a lower bound and a upper bound; you have to create a constructor that receive a value for lower bound and a value for upper bound.

> Create a default ctor that is unbound on both upper and lower values.

A default constructor is a constructor that receive no parameters. If I understand correctly, the default constructor has to set special values for upper bound and lower bound corresponding to unbound values

> Create a constexpr member for kUnboundLower and kUnboundUpper.

Not sure but I suppose that `kUnboudLower` and `kUnboundUpper` are the special unbound values for lower and upper bound; they are `constexpr` so they are `static`.

By example, something as

```
#include <limits> // for std::numeric_limits

class range
 {
   private:
      static constexpr int kUnboundLower { std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
      static constexpr int kUnboundUpper { std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

      int lBound;
      int uBound;

   public:
      // default constructor
      range () : lBound{kUnboundLower}, uBound{kUnboundUpper}
       { }

      // constructor with values
      range (int l, int u) : lBound{l}, uBound{u}
       { }

      // ......
 };
```